# JMeter random function ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)} limitation

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I just started performance/load testing using JMeter and I am using a JMeter funtion "${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}" to generate random string in my payload so I want to know the disadvantages or limitations of this function which might cause issue in future when I put thousands of requests load on my system.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely OK to use this function, the chance that it will become a bottleneck is minimal as it has very low footprint.

However well-behaved tests should be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) therefore it might make sense to pre-generate thousands of random strings and write them to a file and use i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for reading it from the file.

In general monitoring the baseline OS health metrics of JMeter machine (or machines if you're [running JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)) is a very good practice because if JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough you might not be able to achieve the desired load so make sure to check whether JMeter machines have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, disk and network. You can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.

Comment: Thank you... you points are valid but I found another better option during my research that instead of using ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)} function, we can you the GUID function as it make sure to generate the new and unique string every time during execution. please read https://thetesttherapist.com/2018/07/13/generate-guid-in-apache-jmeter/